# In Java thread code "New instance ignored" warning

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, compiler-warnings

So I tried to run this code in NetBeans IDE 11.1 and it shows the error of "New Instance Ignored". My standard textbook has no mention of the warning in the below code. Why is this error being displayed and what can I do to resolve it? And starting a new thread in constructor? Is there a problem with that too?

=======

```
class NewThread1 implements Runnable {
    Thread t1;
    NewThread1() {
        t1 = new Thread();
        System.out.println("Thread : " + t1.getName());
        t1.start();  //Starting new thread in a constructor
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("When NewThread.i = " + i);
                t1.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("t1 interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("t1 ends.");
    }
}

public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewThread1();  //New Instance Being Ignored 
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("When main.i = " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread end.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an error, at least from the perspective of the Java language (your ide may be configured to make it an error though). Ignoring a new instance is legal, but... Why create it of you don't then use it?

Comment: It's a warning. It is being used... as the constructor is being called and thus the thread is being created.

Comment: it's not being used *usefully*. Starting threads in a constructor is not good style; and you can't do something like wait for the thread to complete.

Comment: Side effects in constructors are bad practice. A constructor should construct an object, not start a thread. Besides, what's the point of creating and starting a Thread that doesn't do anything? And finally, sleep is a static method, not an instance method. It makes the **current** thread sleep, and should be called using Thread.sleep().

Comment: Right now your program creates something called `NewThread` (which is a kind of thread), and then does nothing with it. It doesn't start it, so it's `run()` method actually never being called. _Inside_ the constructor of the `NewThread`, it creates another generic empty thread. It does start the thread, but since the thread is empty, JVM will just allocate it some resources, at which point it will just exit and release those resources back to the JVM (because it's empty).

Comment: Actually it is my first code in multi threading, so that's why I didn't do much in the code. Okay I get it! Think I'll just make it start in the main method. Will that still generate a warning?